# Why are there concentric rings around a laser spot on the hand?

Tags: visible-light, laser

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

You see, the outermost ring is red and then purple and then there is a small black region after which there is yellow and finally white. Why are these concentric rings formed and why are the colors so symmetrically arranged?

Comment: What kind of a laser is that?

Comment: here's the video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_970515&feature=iv&src_vid=y3SBSbsdiYg&v=lW4Uq_2VPhE

Answer (score 2):

The following is just a guess. Judging by the white spot in the center, this laser's radiation is relatively broadband. Outside the resonator the beam diverges due to diffraction. The longer-wavelength part of the spectrum diverges more, so the periphery of the beam is read. The intermediate colors represent spectra with wavelength limited from below (shorter-wavelength radiation diverges less), and the limit wavelength decreases as we move towards the center. Therefore, we have a broadband radiation in the center, so it looks white. (Probably, similar processes take place in the resonator as well, so the longer-wavelength part of the beam is broader inside the resonator as well). I cannot be sure that the above reasoning is free from errors.